# Get element count from bottom with css selector

Tags: css, automation, css-selectors, ui-automation, testcafe

I'm using testcafe for creating automation testscript and have problem.
I have select with using nth(-1) for get the last element. But how we can count the prevSibling element from the last element ?

action = (line) => Selector().nth(-1).prevSibling(`tr:nth-child(${line})`)
so if i want use action locator for the line 4 count from bottom , what line i need to input in that locator

Comment: Have you looked into nth-last-child? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-child

Answer (score 0):

To get `prevSibling` of the last element you can use the following selector:

```
await t.click(Selector('tr').nth(-1).prevSibling(-1));
```

However, I do not see any difference with the following selector:

```
await t.click(Selector('tr').nth(-2));
```